# ASP.NET AJAX application extremely slow over VPN

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.NET AJAX intranet application that has been running for a few months. It runs reasonably fast on the LAN.

However when going over a VPN it slows down dramatically. Even taking line speed into account its takes like 60 seconds to change a page. I eventually got a vmware up and running to test the VPN speed, so the connection is super fast, but it still takes the same amount of time. I can even remote desktop over the VPN to the VMware and its perfect.

This makes me think that its has nothing to do with line speed. FYI I am using Hamachi.

I have tried other VPN software and it gives the same results.

I am really stuck... any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have noticed that before, but I never had any complains about that (from customers). But I would like to know about anything you figured out here. Upped!

Comment: When you look at the response times in FireBug, are the response times taking longer? and/or the transfer times?  Any extra info you could add?

Comment: I am not sure where I workout the response times/transfer times? I have not used firebug much in the past.

Comment: I am feeling my way around firebug... does this help?

createCallback() 2 0.32% 0.043ms 13.059ms 6.53ms 5.805ms 7.254ms

Comment: NET is showing that its loaded 23 items, 136KB in 703ms.

Comment: In the console its showing Profile (13.233ms, 292 calls)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem was due to trying to do a dns lookup in the code. Changed to just the IP and now working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add system counters for "Byte per second" and other similar parameters of you network. This helps you to figure out the bottleneck of you system.

Comment: Not sure how I can use this to pinpoint the problem with the ASP.NET code? I am fairly sure that there is no problem with the network. I can run other asp.net applications without any problems.